# How did Taimanov lose this game to Karpov?

Tags: history

I can't understand how Taimanov (playing White) resigned in the following position against Karpov from the Moscow team leagues in 1973:

[image]

After 40.Rc2 or 40.d5 the position seems to be equal. I know Taimanov was notorious for getting into time trouble. Did he just forfeit on time?

Comment: Rc2 Nxf3+? followed by Nxe4 maybe? I think that sided knigth is stronger than it looks

Comment: Stockfish actually favors `d5` over `Rc2`, but its mostly a draw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the book "How Karpov Wins" by Edmar Mednis it is stated on page 174 that "White overstepped the time limit and lost". The book seems to be fully available on Google books and has a lot more analysis of the match.

https://books.google.com.au/books?id=x8MV0uoAJp0C

Comment: last move of time control too, what a bummer

Comment: @CecilDeVere ah you mean just 1 more move until the players get the time bonus?